# Optimize: Excel VBA Macro to delete the bottom rows of a merged cell

Tags: excel, vba, performance, function, optimization

I got it working just fine, but it is painfully slow.  The first function that renames some cells runs really quick, but the while loop that deletes certain merged cell rows takes over a minute for multiple sheets.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, rowtofilter).End(xlUp).Row

'Search for merged cells and not "string1" in column2 and not "string2" in column4, replace text
For i = rowtofilter To LastRow
    If Range(ColumnLetter1 & i).MergeArea.Cells.Count > 1 And Range(ColumnLetter2 & i) <> "string1" And Range(ColumnLetter4 & i) <> "string2" Then
        Range(ColumnLetter3 & i).Value = "Merged Cells"
    End If
Next i

'Search for merged cells and not "string1" in column2 and not "string2" in column4, delete rows
i = LastRow - rowtofilter
Do While i > (rowtofilter - 1)
    If Range(ColumnLetter1 & i).Value = 0 And Range(ColumnLetter2 & i) <> "string1" And Range(ColumnLetter4 & i) <> "string2" Then
        Range(ColumnLetter1 & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    i = i - 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't yet, add `application.screenupdating=false` at the beginning and  `application.screenupdating=true` at the end of your code to speed things up.

Then, if still slow, do the deletion all at once:

```
Dim rgToDelete As Range

i = LastRow - rowtofilter
Do While i > (rowtofilter - 1)
    If Range(ColumnLetter1 & i).Value = 0 And Range(ColumnLetter2 & i) <> "string1" And Range(ColumnLetter4 & i) <> "string2" Then
        If rgToDelete Is Nothing Then 
             Set rgToDelete = Range(ColumnLetter1 & i) 
        Else 
             Set rgToDelete = Union(rgToDelete , Range(ColumnLetter1 & i))
        End If
    End If
    i = i - 1
Loop


rgToDelete .EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: I do have screenupdating setup and automatic calculation set already.  Thank you for this, I knew there was a more elegant way to do it.  Before I got your answer I just created a macro that hid each row and it seemed to do the trick too.

Comment: Often, the best way to do a loop is to not do a loop. Use .autofilter to select the right cells, then use `range.specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).entirerow.delete` to clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of using Rows.Count, only work with the UsedRange. `Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`
2. Hide the sheet while doing the second bit. Excel wants to update the screen with every deleted row. By hiding the sheet, you stop that nonsense. `Worksheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden`
3. If there are calculations based on the rows being deleted, turn off automatic calculations while doing the delete. In fact, you might just do it anyway. This will prevent Excel from recalculating the sheet on every delete. `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Remember to turn everything back on when you're done.

*Note that, in the above examples, Worksheet should be replaced by a reference to whatever worksheet you are using.

Comment: Does the Application.ScreenUpdating = False do the same thing as hiding the sheet all together?